# Which is faster to load CSV file or multiple INSERT commands in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Just need some advice here. Because I have a table that has 45,000 rows. What I did is I export the table as a multiple INSERT command. But the estimated time is too long. Which is faster to load in the sql? A rows that is exported as CSV or rows that exported as a multiple INSERT command?

Comment: But the estimated time is too long. - how did you get this estimation?

Comment: I run this in a SQL browser software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LOAD DATA INFILE` is the fastest.

hello, so you are dumping table by your own program. if loading speed is important. please consider belows:

- ensure that multiple `INSERT INTO .. VALUES (...), (...)`
- Disable INDEX before loading, enable after loading. This is faster.
- `LOAD DATA INFILE` is super faster than multiple INSERT but, has trade-off. maintance and handling escaping.
- BTW, I thing `mysqldump` is better than others.

how long takes to load 45,000 rows?

Comment: Ok sorry for my late reply. As of now it takes 35 mins. But it is not done yet.

Comment: @Jerielle thanks. as you know, load time depends your schema and data. but it's too late (2.15 rows per sec?). are you loading while there is another process? have you checked `SHOW PROCESSLIST` while loading?

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` is faster, because you are skip parsing of csv.

If your table at `MyISAM`, you can copy files: `*.frm`, `*.myi`, `*.myd` and this migration will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, loading a csv is almost always faster with large datasets; it is built for mass loading.

See here for more info 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16809/why-is-load-data-infile-faster-than-normal-insert-statements